# How can sed be used, with variables names, without adding a trailing newline in macOS?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to make an index for a tex document. To make the process faster, I made a list of words in a CSV file named "`idxprep.csv`" that have in it the words to look for and the string to replace (the structure (`dput` (in R)) of the CSV is available at the end of the post). I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.

Here is the script that I'm using to search and replace the words in the `CSV` into the `tex` file.

```
# This is just a variable that will raise slowly after changing the words 
i=1 
j=2 # this is the same as the one above, just that it refers to j=i+1

# This is the tex file in which there is the text to change. 
PART="ttest.tex" 


# Making a copy of the `tex` file and append a number to it (`i`) and adds `_ind.tex` 
cp ~/Desktop/$PART ~/Desktop/${PART%.tex}.${i}_ind.tex 

# get all the columns and rename them to use the columns in variables 
while IFS="," read -r v1 v2 srch v4 v5 v6 rp remainder 
do
    old=$srch
    new=$rp

 # this is to keep weird characters      
    escOld=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<< "$old") 
 # this is to keep weird characters 
    escNew=$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$new") 

 # This is the command to find/replace 
    sed "s/$escOld/$escNew/g" ~/Desktop/${PART%.tex}.${i}_ind.tex >  ~/Desktop/${PART%.tex}.${j}_ind.tex

  ((i=i+1)) # increment both numbers 
  ((j=j+1))

# Input the file 
done < ~/Desktop/idxprep.csv
```

I have a `.tex` file called "`ttest.tex`" that contains this:

```
I think that this example won't involve Darwin's finches' nests, but it might talk about their adaptive radiation.
```

But the final output is this:

```
I think that this example won't involve Darwin's finches'\index{Darwin's finches}
 nests, but it might talk about their adaptive radiation\index{adaptive radiation}
.
```

Is there a way to have an output that *doesn't* contain newlines at the places where the words were replaced? Expect output:

```
I think that this example won't involve Darwin's finches'\index{Darwin's finches} nests, but it might talk about their adaptive radiation\index{adaptive radiation}.
```

Here is the CSV

```
structure(list(X7 = c(7L, 9L, 9L), X1 = c(2L, 1L, 2L), Darwin.s.finches. = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("adaptive radiation", "Adaptive radiation", 
"Darwin's finches "), class = "factor"), X.index. = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "\\index{", class = "factor"), Darwin.s.finches = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("adaptive radiation", "Darwin's finches"), class = "factor"), 
    X. = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("}", "} "), class = "factor"), 
    Darwin.s.finches..index.Darwin.s.finches. = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("adaptive radiation\\index{adaptive radiation}", 
    "Adaptive radiation\\index{adaptive radiation}", "Darwin's finches \\index{Darwin's finches} "
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Here is the raw CSV:

```
7,1,Darwin's finches',\index{,Darwin's finches,},Darwin's finches'\index{Darwin's finches}
7,2,Darwin's finches ,\index{,Darwin's finches,} ,Darwin's finches \index{Darwin's finches} 
9,1,adaptive radiation,\index{,adaptive radiation,},adaptive radiation\index{adaptive radiation}
9,2,Adaptive radiation,\index{,adaptive radiation,},Adaptive radiation\index{adaptive radiation}
```

Comment: Your "CSV" file doesn't look like any CSV file I've ever seen.  What does CSV stand for in this context — it isn't a normal 'comma-separated values' (or 'character-separated values') file.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to add the CSV... I'm used to using ```dput``` function in R and posting it here. I added the raw CSV within the post